# Make r2 -i <script> use python3 rather than python2

Tags: radare2

I have a r2 script that I'm running with `r2 -i script.py test.x`. By default this command uses python2. How can I get it to use python3? I couldn't find anything in the config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*OP did not mention their OS, thus I assume the OS is Linux.*

---

radare2 is using the default `python` version on your machine. That means that, probably, `/usr/bin/python` on your machine points to `/usr/bin/python2.7`. You can check it by executing `readlink` on the file:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

The solution for this should be quite straightforward. Simply, changing where `python` points to should do the trick. You can do this by executing `ln` and point `python` to `python3` on your machine:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

---

### Demo Time

Imagine the following Python script which simply prints the version of Python:

```
$ cat demo.py
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

This is script is compatible with both Python2 and Python3.

Now, let's try to execute radare2 with this initialization script, without changing the symlink of `/usr/bin/python`. i.e. `python` would point to python2.

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7

$ r2 -q -i demo.py -
2.7.12
```

As you can see, radare2 executed the init script and printed "2.7.12".

Now, let's modify the symlink to point to `python3` and test the script again:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

$ readlink -f /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python3.5

$ r2 -q -i demo.py -
3.5.2
```

As you requested, now `python3` was executed instead of `python2`.

If you want `python` to point to `python2`, you can revert it back using the same command:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```